# Selecting and using primary key in a query

Tags: php, mysql

I have a table

```
----------------------------------------------------------
| id | Bizid |    Email     | Username | Password | Salt |
 ---------------------------------------------------------
| 6  |   5   |test@test.com | TestUser | 21412bjkb| 4151 |
----------------------------------------------------------
```

where Bizid references the primary key of another table.

I am currently trying to use the primary key of this table (id) in a query

```
<?PHP
if(@$_POST['addcat']=="Submit")
{
include("cxn.inc");
$userid=$_SESSION['UserId'];
$cat=$_POST['category'];
$branch="SELECT id WHERE Bizid=$userid";<--This query
$getbranch=mysqli_query($cxn,$branch) or die(mysqli_error($cxn));<--This query
$addcat="INSERT INTO categories (Business,Branch,Category) VALUES($userid,$getbranch,$cat)";
$runcat=mysqli_query($cxn,$addcat) or die (mysqli_error($cxn));
$success="Category added successfully";
}
?>
```

but i am getting the error

```
You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'WHERE Bizid=5' at line 1
```

I cant seem to see what exactly is wrong with my code above, unless i am unable to use primary keys in queries like what i am doing above.

If so, could anyone kindly point me in the right direction to go, of suggest a workaround?

Thanks!

PS:i'm new to coding, and am trying to pick things up as i go.

Comment: `FROM` where do you select the Bizid? You are missing the `FROM` statment from your query.

Comment: Upvoted as it's a clear question, but voted to close as it is quite localised, however there's plenty of answers below! FWIW, since variables should be named according to what they contain, consider renaming `$branch` to `$sql` or `$branchSql`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You didn't specified `FROM tableName`.

```
$branch="SELECT id FROM tableName WHERE Bizid=$userid";
                   ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

Answer (score 2):

```
$branch = "SELECT id FROM table_name WHERE Bizid=$userid";
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$branch="SELECT id WHERE Bizid=$userid";<--This query
```

should be

```
$branch="SELECT id FROM TABLE_NAME WHERE Bizid=$userid";
```

Answer (score 0):

**syntax:**..you didnt specify from which table you are fetching your data

```
SELECT [cloumn1,column2,....] FROM table_name WHERE [condition];
```